# General System Preferences won't save on Max OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, settings

Under System Preferences > General, there seems to be one setting, on my computer, that won't save. Regardless of what I set it to, it always reverts to "Always":

[image: picture of max osx mavericks scrolling settings under system preferences > general]

I have tried the following:

1. Going to my home folder, selecting "Get Info," and applying R+W to all enclosed folders. This [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3159542?tstart=0) was detailed on the Apple support forums. I have also tried it programatically with `chmod 755`.
2. Deleting the `com.apple.systempreferences.plist` file under `/Library/Preferences`, logging out, and logging back in.

I decided to make a new user account and see whether the problem would be replicated. However, under this new account, I was able to change this setting to "When scrolling" or "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad." It applied the new setting.

What could be going wrong and how can I go about fixing this? I really don't want my scrollbars to show all the time, especially if I'm not using a mouse.

Comment: Could it be a app that is overwriting your settings. To test start in safe mode, very it works, then add app one by one.

Comment: @Buscar웃 But then why would I be able to change settings on another user account?

Comment: Because that user account might not have that application.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Is there a way to easily check whether a user account has access to certain apps?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just tried the safe booting thing. The setting still won't save.

Comment: In case you have a problem with preferences settings not saving, that indicates your user ACL need repair. Follow instructions here: http://macs.about.com/od/Troubleshooting/qt/Mac-Troubleshooting-Reset-User-Account-Permissions.htm

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just followed that guide to a T—didn't work. I haven't a clue as to what could be causing this. I guess it'd be better to make a new admin account and transfer all my data (except this would probably cause the problem to be transferred over along with my files).

Comment: Then you definitely have a app doing it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Is the a way to find out which app is affecting which settings?

Comment: Maybe, but I would just use the Activity monitor and close them from there one by one.